# Can't join Minecraft PE version 8.1, says outdated server?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Trying to connect my from son's iPod 4 to my iPod 4s. Both are using iOS6, both playing Minecraft version 8.1. My iPhone joins to my iPad no problem but not to the iPhone 4. If I try to connect from the iPhone4 it says 'outdated server' if I try to connect from my iPhone 4S the wifi world from the iPhone4 doesn't even show up as an option to connect to.  Same version same wifi network, what am I missing?

Answer (score 5):

This means that the server you are attempting play on a world/server is using an outdated version of the game, therefore not allow you to play. Say, you have Minecraft Pocket Edition 0.9.0, and you attempted to connect to a server/world using 0.8.0, you'd get that error message.

Answer (score 2):

It's basically the devices itself thats causing the problem(s). They're that outdated that they can barely connect with each other. So in this case, make sure that both devices are at the highest maximum update possible, and then try to connect with each other again.

But if this still doesn't work, the problem is either within your internet router, or it's either a bug on the game or the device itself.

Hope this helps! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Well, me and my brother were trying to play Minecraft together but it unfortunately said "This client/server is outdated" so we made sure we are on the same network/wifi and we had the highest possible updates. If that does not work there is a bug in the game or your network router or just your device.